# Comparing Multiple Lists in Python 3.X

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I'm not sure how to explain it so here's an example:

```
array = ["x","x","x"]

if array == ["x","2","3"] or ["1","x","3"] or ["1","2","x"]:
    print ("hello")
```

Basically, how could I get this to only print hello if it is equal to **one** of those lists?

Comment: It looks like you might be able to simplify this particular case to `if array.count("x") == 1:`... :)

Answer (score 0):

Check if it is contained in a `list` of `lists`:

```
array = ["x","x","x"]

if array in [["x","2","3"],["1","x","3"],["1","2","x"]]:
    print ("hello")
```

Comment: Where did the `x, x, x` case come from? That's not in OP's post.

Answer (score 0):

You construct a temporary tuple (can be also list or set, but tuple is better) and check if it contains the value:

```
if array in (["x","2","3"], ["1","x","3"], ["1","2","x"]):
    print ("hello")
```